# Imprimir registros desde un modulo ensamblador

Tags: c, ensamblador, nasm, assembly

Estoy intentando mostrar dos números desde un modulo ensamblador (aquí mi problema es mostrar los registros que contienen los parámetros), el programa principal esta en C donde envió 2 parámetros (a,b) al modulo en ensamblador, Programa principal

```
//Compilacion:  gcc -m32 -o imprimir prueba.c contenido.o
#include <stdio.h>
extern void contenido(int A, int B);
int main()
{   
    int a;
    int b;
    //Rotulo
    printf("------------------------------------------------\n");
    //Asignamos valor por teclado
    printf("Ingrese A: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    
    printf("Ingrese B: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    printf(">>>Recorrido:\n");
    
    contenido(a,b);
  return 0;
}
```

Modulo en ensamblador nasm que muestra los datos. Aquí mi problema.

```
;Compilacion    :   nasm -f elf contenido.asm
section .bss
nroB resd 1
nroA resd 1

section .text
global contenido

contenido:
;Crear un marco de la pila 
push ebp
mov ebp,esp

;leer los parametros de la pila
mov eax,[ebp+8]
mov [nroA],eax

mov eax,[ebp+12]
mov [nroB],eax

;MOSTAR EN PANTALLA


salirv:
;Liberar marco de pila
pop ebp
;Regresar ret
ret
```

Como puedo mostrar o imprimir los registros que contienen los parámetros? Encontré este codigo

```
    ;MOSTAR EN PANTALLA
mov dl,[nroA] ;numero a exhibir
add dl,48 ;sumandole 48 al contenido ; de AL se lo trasforma en ASCII
mov ah,2
int 21h ;muestra el ASCII de AL
```

Y al compilar el modulo, luego el programa principal en C luego ingresar los numeros tal como hace el programa principal, obtengo el siguiente error `Violación de segmento` Estaré muy agradecido con sus consejos.

Comment: En lo de mostrar pantalla estas pasando a dl (registro de 1byte) un int de c que son 2bytes, puede que ande por ahí los tiros. Prueba pasándole un char.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para que nuestros programas puedan interactuar con el usuario, utilizaremos la librería `io.mac`, la cual contiene macros para leer datos desde el teclado, mostrar resultados a través
del monitor y otras operaciones de entrada/salida.

- La instrucción PutStr permite mostrar una cadena a través del
  monitor.
- La instrucción PutInt permite mostrar un entero a través del monitor.
- La instrucción PutLint, permite mostrar un entero largo a    través
  del monitor.
- La instrucción GetInt, permite leer un entero    desde el teclado.

Para poder utilizar el macro añadir `%include "io.mac"` antes de iniciar el código, ademas deben estar en la misma carpeta los siguientes 2 archivos, `io.o` y `io.mac` que lo puedes descargar en este [enlace](http://service.scs.carleton.ca/sivarama/org_book/org_book_web/source_code.html) que se encuentra dento de `/linux_nasm_progs/Linux_IOfiles/`
Aquí la [documentacion](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.16) para más.

Por tanto para poder usar, al compilar tenemos que enlazar dichos macros, añadiendo a `gcc -m32 -o imprimir arhivo_en_C.c nombre_archivo_ensamblador_ya_compilado.o` por  `gcc -m32 -o imprimir arhivo_en_C.c nombre_archivo_ensamblador_ya_compilado.o io.o` .
De igual manera si se quiere usar solamente en ensamblador, al antes compilar seria enlazar agregando `io.o` de la siguiente forma `ld -m elf_i386 -s -o nombre_de_programa_aEjecutar arhivo_en_ensamblador.o io.o`

Para la solución de este problema utilizamos `PutLint eax` o sea el registro a mostrar y tambien agregando io.o al compilar de la siguiente forma `gcc -m32 -o imprimir prueba.c contenido.o io.o`